# How do I create a custom column in Power BI that adds the values in existing columns

Tags: powerbi

I have a table(table attached) that has ages of children in separate columns and I want to create a custom column PreK(ages 0-4) to show the total PreK aged children by region, School-aged children column 5-18 etc. I would like to be able to do this in Power BI

*your text*

[image]

I need help creating such a table.

Comment: Can you provide more details and what is expected output.

Comment: In PowerQuery, create a Custom Column and simply add the column (eg `[col1] + [col2]` ). Alternatively, with DAX, create a Calculated Column with the same (`Prek = [col1] + [col2]`).